# How to set html table responsive for mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

```css
<style>
    
   @media only screen and (max-width: 417px) {
    table {
        display: block;
    }
}
  table, thead, tbody, tfoot, tr, th, td {
    display: block; /* Set all of our table elements to display type block */
}
 
/* And here we will set our table to act normally after we hit 1024px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    table { display: table; }
    thead { display: table-header-group; }
    tbody { display: table-row-group; }
    tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
    tr { display: table-row; }
    th, td { display: table-cell; }
}  
    
 td:first-child {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
 
td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(4) {
    padding: 10px;
}
 
td {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}   
    
    
    </style>
```

Hi I am working on bigcommerce, It is my code for cart, I want help to make cart content responsive on small screens for eg mobile  I was wondering is it possible to make html table responsive for mobile, It is looking good on tab but not on mobile, Thank you in advance

```
<tr>
        <td class="CartThumb" style="%%GLOBAL_HideThumbColumn%%">
            %%GLOBAL_ProductImage%%&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="ProductName" colspan="%%GLOBAL_ProductNameSpan%%">
            <a href="%%GLOBAL_ProductLink%%">%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%</a>%%GLOBAL_ProductOptions%%
            <br>
            %%GLOBAL_ProductAvailability%%
            <div class="CartExpectedReleaseDate" style="%%GLOBAL_HideExpectedReleaseDate%%">(%%GLOBAL_ProductExpectedReleaseDate%%)</div>
            %%GLOBAL_EventDate%%
            <div style="%%GLOBAL_HideWrappingOptions%%" class="WrappingOptions">
                %%LNG_GiftWrapping%%:
                %%GLOBAL_GiftWrappingName%%
                <a href="#" onclick="Cart.ManageGiftWrapping('%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%');" style="%%GLOBAL_HideGiftWrappingAdd%%">%%LNG_Add%%</a>
                <span style="%%GLOBAL_HideGiftWrappingEdit%%">
                    (<a href="#" onclick="Cart.ManageGiftWrapping('%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%');">%%LNG_Change%%</a> %%LNG_Or%% <a href="cart.php?action=remove_giftwrapping&amp;item_id=%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%" onclick="return Cart.RemoveGiftWrapping();">%%LNG_Remove%%</a>)
                </span>
                <br>
                <span style="%%GLOBAL_HideGiftMessagePreview%%">
                    %%LNG_GiftMessage%%:
                    %%GLOBAL_GiftMessagePreview%%
                </span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center" class="CartItemQuantity">
            %%GLOBAL_CartItemQty%%

        </td>
        <td align="center" class="CartItemIndividualPrice">
            %%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%
        </td>
        <td align="right" class="CartItemTotalPrice"><em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_ProductTotal%%</em>

        </td>

        <td>
             <div style="%%GLOBAL_HideCartItemRemove%%">


                <a href="cart.php?action=remove&amp;item=%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%" onclick="Cart.RemoveItem('%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%'); return false;" class="CartRemoveLink" title="%%LNG_Remove%%">&nbsp;</a>
            </div>
        </td>        


    </tr>
```

set HTML table responsive for mobile

Comment: Have you tried anything with CSS?

Comment: I have tried this

Comment: Only show relevant code, I'm not sure what you expect us to modify if you don't show us any of your CSS.

Comment: First make the table as narrow as possible: In css make the width of columns as small as possible (and I mean <td>) in html make it without content just for now... Then add elements to it and watch how it changes. There is nothing wrong with mobile just tables have a certain width if you add padding, margins, widths of every cell and the table + other elements on your site, it just can't fit.... Also at least for me it is not enough data to find a solution.... I made a site with a lot of table content, and even narrowing it only made it readable but not necessary nice looking.. on mobiles.

Comment: Tables should only be used for rendering of tabular data. If it's just layout that you want, tables should not be used. CSS is for layout.

Comment: How do you want it to look on mobile?  Without that information, we can't really help you achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS to style, applying the width of the tables as a % will make it responsive in a sense. Resizing the screen, it will shrink. However, it may become cramped and in that case you can use *media queries* to set breakpoints of different styles once the screen shrinks to a certain point.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Please don't link to W3 Schools. It's well-known to have out of date or flat out wrong information and it just trains a new batch of rookies to rely on it. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) or the [W3C](http://w3.org) are the best resources.

Comment: The page I linked to is easier to understand because of its layout and that page is not outdated in any way so I don’t see what’s wrong with posting that link.

Comment: As I've mentioned, W3 Schools is often outdated or flat out wrong. Today that page may be OK, but it's likely that it won't be in the future and since SO is a knowledge base, it's best to provide links to reputable sources. The MDN pages on Media Queries are just as easy to read and much more comprehensive.